# What is the meaning of <xml lang="..">

Tags: xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<vxml version="2.0" xml:lang="..">
```

In the XML Snippet given above, the XML root has an attribute xml:lang value pointing to ".." value. 
what is the meaning of ".." here ?

Comment: AFAIK, such a value likely has no meaning, aside from a placeholder for whoever wrote the document. Could it be an example document where whoever is writing a real document is supposed to insert the appropriate language code?

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of the xml:lang attribute are defined in the XML recommendation §2.12:

> A special attribute named xml:lang may be inserted in documents to
>   specify the language used in the contents and attribute values of any
>   element in an XML document. In valid documents, this attribute, like
>   any other, must be declared if it is used. The values of the attribute
>   are language identifiers as defined by [IETF BCP 47], Tags for the
>   Identification of Languages; in addition, the empty string may be
>   specified.

So it the author writes `<quote xml:lang="de">Alle Menschen werden Brüder</quote>` then the attribute is giving anyone who reads the document a clue that the quotation is in German.

Of course, it's only a convention and a clue. The document would not become invalid if the quotation were actually in French.

In your example you had `xml:lang=".."`. I'm not sure if you were telling us that the actual value of the attribute was two full stops. That wouldn't be a valid language identifier according to IETF BCP 47. Unfortunately the spec is vague about how that should be handled; although it says "the values of the attribute are language identifiers", it doesn't say what the parser should do if it finds a value that isn't.